# Couchbase REST API vs CLI

Tags: rest, couchbase

I'm trying to use the REST API on Couchbase 2.2 and I'm finding two things that I cannot seem to do via REST:

1. Init a new cluster when no other nodes exist. 
   CLI version: 
   `couchbase-cli cluster-init -u admin -p mypw -c localhost:8091 --cluster-init-ramsize=1024`
2. Remove a healthy node from the cluster.
   CLI version: 
   `couchbase-cli rebalance -u admin -p mypw -c 10.10.1.10:8091 --server-remove=10.10.1.12`

As for removing a node, I've tried:

```
curl -u admin:mypw -d otpNode=ns_1@10.10.1.12 \
http://10.10.1.10:8091/controller/ejectNode
```

Which returns: "Cannot remove active server."

I've also tried:

```
curl -s -u Administrator:myclusterpw \
-d 'ejectedNodes=ns_1%4010.10.1.12&knownNodes=ns_1%4010.10.1.10%2Cns_1%4010.10.1.11' \
http://10.10.1.10:8091/controller/rebalance
```

Which returns: `{"mismatch":1}` (presumably due to the node actually not being marked for ejection?)

Am I crazy, or are there no ways to do these things using curl?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the final node in the cluster, or are you trying to just remove one node from a cluster of more than one machine? I get the same response but I only have one node. I'd have to spin up a cluster to try it again, which I can do...

Comment: Also, the first of the two curl's is the proper syntax. I am asking the team about this right now and will add comment/answer once I get something for you...

Comment: @scalabl3 - I managed to make the removal work below, perhaps you can provide the standardised way to do it :)

Comment: It was probably the missing -X POST in Nate Fox's curl, he was doing a GET :)

Comment: curl will change the request to POST if the -d flag is used. But I agree, it should be specifically stated especially while testing just to be sure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I span up a two node cluster on aws (10.170.76.236 and 10.182.151.86), I was able to remove node 10.182.151.86 using the below curl request

```
curl -v -u Administrator:password -X POST 'http://10.182.151.86:8091/controller/rebalance' -d 'ejectedNodes=ns_1@10.182.151.86&knownNodes=ns_1@10.182.151.86,ns_1@10.170.76.236'
```

That removes the node and performs the rebalance leaving only '10.170.76.236' as the single node.  Running this request below results in 'Cannot remove active server' as you have experienced.

```
curl -u Administrator:password -d otpNode=ns_1@10.170.76.236 http://10.170.76.236:8091/controller/ejectNode
```

This is because you can't remove the last node as you can't perform a rebalance,  this issue is covered here http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-7517

I left the real IP's in that I used so the curl requests are as clear as possible, I've terminated the nodes now though :)

Comment: This works for removing a node. I didnt have the node to eject in the knownNodes list. Now to figure out question #1!

Answer (score 1):

Combo of:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:password -d username=Administrator \
-d password=letmein \
-d port=8091 \
http://localhost:8091/settings/web
```

and

```
curl -X POST -u admin:password -d memoryQuota=400 \
http://localhost:8091/pools/default
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ticket raised against this](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-7517) indicates that the ejectnode command itself won't work by design.

Server needs to either be pending or failover state to use that command seemingly