# Rebalancing after failover a couchbase node

Tags: python, python-requests, couchbase

Setup with 3 nodes in a cluster. After failing over a node (10.90.150.21), gave command to REBALANCE as

```
payload = 'ejectedNodes=ns_1@10.90.150.21&knownNodes=ns_1@10.90.150.21,ns_1@10.90.150.22,ns_1@10.90.150.23'

url = "http://10.90.150.21:8091/controller/rebalance"

x3 = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=(un, pwd))
```

But response received as 400. So what is the correct command i have to use to rebalance a couchbase node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 400 response means your request is invalid. The first thing that could be causing it is constructing your "payload" yourself. You should instead let requests take care of that for you like so:

```
payload = {'ejectedNodes': 'ns_1@10.90.150.21', 'knownNodes': 'ns_1@10.90.150.21,ns_1@10.90.150.22,ns_1@10.90.150.23'}
requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=(un, pwd))
```

Judging by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528364/couchbase-rest-api-vs-cli) this code should now work. Requests will properly encode everything and set the appropriate headers.